# Invariant subspaces of a linear transformation or a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question about a concept in linear algebra that is also applied in representation theory. I asked a similar question there, but I realised that this is more a question on fundamental linear algebra. I will consider a finite-dimensional vector space $V \cong K^n$, where $K$ is the field over which $V$ is defined. In this case, we can identify a matrix with a linear transformation from $V$ to $V$ given a basis. Now the question is about the opposite and I want to determine the invariant subspaces of the linear map.

I am for example given a matrix of the following form:

> $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\
>             0&-1 }$.

From this matrix, I can easily see that span$\{e_1\}$, span$\{e_2\}$ form invariant subspaces of the matrix. Now my problem is that $A$ is a matrix defined with respect to a certain basis, let us call $\mathcal{F}=\{f_1,f_2\}$. But $e_1$ in the matrix is determined as follows: $A(f_1)=f_1$ where $A$ now is a linear map from $V$ to $V$. Using a coordinate map we can define $\phi(f_1)=e_1$ which gives an isomorphism between the standard basis and $\mathcal{F}$, such that $(f_1)_{\mathcal{F}}=e_1$. And that is exactly my confusion.

People talk about invariant subspaces of a matrix, but span$\{e_1\}$, span$\{e_2\}$ are not the eigenvectors of the linear map but of the matrix. The eigenvectors of the linear map in this case are just the basis vectors of $\mathcal{F}$. Note that $\mathcal{F}$ could be the standard basis but I talk about $A$ with respect to some basis (not known).

Now we can write $V=W_1 \oplus W_2$ for two invariant subspaces, but I do not understand why some references tend to choose just the eigenspaces of the matrix as $W_1$ and $W_2$ instead of the eigenspaces of the linear operator. Is this because of the isomorphism $\phi(a_i)=e_i$ I stated earlier or this is something that is specific to representation theory. Hope that somebody can clarify this.

Comment: There's a lot of confusion going on here. What are your $e_1$ and $e_2$? How are they different from $f_1$ and $f_2$? What exactly do you mean when you speak of $\operatorname{span}\{e_1\}$? And what do you mean when you say "... $e_1$ in the matrix ..."? And can you reconcile your answers to the last two questions?

Comment: $e_1 = (10)^T $ so the standard basis vector. So span$\{e_1\}$ is span$\{(10)^T\}$, the first column vector of the matrix. The basis $F$ is some basis. I do not know whether the matrix is with respect to $\{e_1,e_2\}$ or some other basis $\mathcal{F}$. $A$ is therefore a matrix with respect to some basis, which I call $\mathcal{F}$ but this basis is not known but you know since $dim(V)<\infty$ there must be some basis that gives this basis given a linear map $A : V \rightarrow V$ such that $ A = \pmatrix{ A(f_1)_F A(f_2)_F }$. Now I wonder why some reference use eigenvectors of the matrix ..

Comment: To write $V=W_1 \oplus W_2$ they use that $V= span\{e_1\} \oplus span\{e_2\}$ but shouldn’t this be as follows: $ V= span\{f_1\} \oplus span\{f_2\}$ ? This because the column vectors in the matrix are images of basis vectors of $\mathcal{F}$. Therefore the column vectors are in fact coordinate vectors i.e. for example $(f_1)_{\mathcal{F}} = (10)^T=e_1$. The eigenvectors of the linear map are therefore $\{f_1,f_2\}$. Hope this makes my post more clear.